# populate a dense dataframe given a key-value dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a key-value dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=['X','Y','val'],data= [['a','z',5],['b','g',3],['b','y',6],['e','r',9]])
>    X Y val
   0 a z   5
   1 b g   3
   2 b y   6
   3 e r   9
```

Which I'd like to convert into a denser dataframe:

```
     X z g y r
   0 a 5 0 0 0
   1 b 0 3 6 0
   2 e 0 0 0 9
```

Before I resort to a pure-python I was wondering if there was a simple way to do this with pandas.

Comment: It's easy to pivot to get this without the empty line of `b 0 0 0 0`; is that important?

Comment: Should the 6 be on row 2 rather than row 1?

Comment: fixed row 2, it was a typo! thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.reshape.get_dummies.html):

```
In [11]: dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['Y'])

In [12]: dummies
Out[12]: 
   g  r  y  z
0  0  0  0  1
1  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  0
3  0  1  0  0
```

and then [multiply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) by the val column:

```
In [13]: res = dummies.mul(df['val'], axis=0)

In [14]: res
Out[14]: 
   g  r  y  z
0  0  0  0  5
1  3  0  0  0
2  0  0  6  0
3  0  9  0  0
```

To fix the index, you could just add the X as this index, you could first apply set_index:

```
In [21]: df1 = df.set_index('X', append=True)

In [22]: df1
Out[22]: 
     Y  val
  X        
0 a  z    5
1 b  g    3
2 b  y    6
3 e  r    9

In [23]: dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['Y'])

In [24]: dummies.mul(df['val'], axis=0)
Out[24]: 
     g  r  y  z
  X            
0 a  0  0  0  5
1 b  3  0  0  0
2 b  0  0  6  0
3 e  0  9  0  0
```

If you wanted to do this [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables-and-cross-tabulations) (you can also use pivot_table):

```
In [31]: df.pivot('X', 'Y').fillna(0)
Out[31]: 
   val         
Y    g  r  y  z
X              
a    0  0  0  5
b    3  0  6  0
e    0  9  0  0
```

Perhaps you want to reset_index, to make X a column (I'm not sure whether than makes sense):

```
In [32]: df.pivot('X', 'Y').fillna(0).reset_index()
Out[32]: 
   X  val         
Y       g  r  y  z
0  a    0  0  0  5
1  b    3  0  6  0
2  e    0  9  0  0
```

For completeness, the [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables-and-cross-tabulations):

```
In [33]: df.pivot_table('val', 'X', 'Y', fill_value=0)
Out[33]: 
Y  g  r  y  z
X            
a  0  0  0  5
b  3  0  6  0
e  0  9  0  0

In [34]: df.pivot_table('val', 'X', 'Y', fill_value=0).reset_index()
Out[34]: 
Y  X  g  r  y  z
0  a  0  0  0  5
1  b  3  0  6  0
2  e  0  9  0  0
```

*Note: the column name are named Y, after reseting the index, not sure if this makes sense (and easy to rectify via `res.columns.name = None`).*

Comment: Hmm.  Using `get_dummies` preserves all the rows the OP wants, but doesn't put the 3 and 6 in the same row; `.pivot("X", "Y").fillna(0)` puts the 3 and 6 in the same row but loses the 0 row.  I'm not sure which is closer to what the OP is after.

Comment: Hmmm, that positioning looks wrong. The thing I'm missing atm is the df['X'] col being part of the index

Comment: Yeah, I guess it could be an error on the OP's part.  +1 anyway. :^)

Comment: :) I see what you're saying. Yeah, depends what they are after. If it's the thing OP wrote they should throw away the first index (as that doesn't make much sense)...

Comment: Yeah sorry about not being clear - the pivot tables where all I was looking for... forgot about those. However after testing out `get_dummies` this works out better for what I need to work with. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that feels more direct. Something akin to `DataFrame.lookup` but for np.put might make sense.

```
def lookup_index(self, row_labels, col_labels):
    values = self.values
    ridx = self.index.get_indexer(row_labels)
    cidx = self.columns.get_indexer(col_labels)
    if (ridx == -1).any():
        raise ValueError('One or more row labels was not found')
    if (cidx == -1).any():
        raise ValueError('One or more column labels was not found')
    flat_index = ridx * len(self.columns) + cidx
    return flat_index

flat_index = lookup_index(df, vals.X, vals.Y)
np.put(df.values, flat_index, vals.val.values)
```

This assumes that `df` has the appropriate columns and index to hold the X/Y values. Here's an ipython notebook http://nbviewer.ipython.org/6454120